# Windows 10 Data Usage Not Showing Up Properly

Tags: networking, windows-10, tcpip

When I try to check my data usage in Windows 10 (ms-settings:datausage) my data usage doesn't show up. On the main screen it says 0MB. When I click "View usage by app" to get more detailed information the page is broken. The "Show usage from" menu is blank.[image: Data usage view usage per app more details]

[image: Data Usage Main Page]

[image: When I try to click the menu]

When I run the dism command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 10.0.18363.592

[==========================100.0%==========================]
Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing should show up. I just again looked at my own and the total usage balances with Windows Explorer. I have checked before and it has always been correct.

1. Run the basic Windows Repairs.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run both:
   (a) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image   /restorehealth
   (b) SFC /SCANNOW

Allow both to finish, restart and test Windows Storage Display.

2. If the above fails to correct the issue, run Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation link.  Choose the second selection, download, run in place and choose the option to Keep Everything to start with.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: When I run the DISM command, I get an error. I updated the question with the error.

Comment: Would posting the log be of any use?

Comment: SFC /SCANNOW said there was a repair in progress and to restart. I restarted and it works again. Not sure if the sfc scan or the reboot fixed it. I had the problems on other machines before. I'll post an update if it happens again and see if the results are similar on other machines...

Comment: Try now the Repair Install step.